# trying to show image of a mammograms with pydicom

Tags: python, numpy, pydicom

`plt.imshow(datasetP2.pixel_array, cmap=plt.cm.bone)`

tried this code on a file provided to me and ended up with this error

````
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
~\AppData\Local\Temp/ipykernel_28228/3373097283.py in <module>
----> 1 plt.imshow(datasetP2.pixel_array, cmap=plt.cm.bone)

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pydicom\dataset.py in __getattr__(self, name)
    834             return {}
    835         # Try the base class attribute getter (fix for issue 332)
--> 836         return object.__getattribute__(self, name)
    837 
    838     @property

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pydicom\dataset.py in pixel_array(self)
   1880             :class:`numpy.ndarray`.
   1881         """
-> 1882         self.convert_pixel_data()
   1883         return cast("numpy.ndarray", self._pixel_array)
   1884 

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pydicom\dataset.py in convert_pixel_data(self, handler_name)
   1442             self._convert_pixel_data_using_handler(handler_name)
   1443         else:
-> 1444             self._convert_pixel_data_without_handler()
   1445 
   1446     def _convert_pixel_data_using_handler(self, name: str) -> None:

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pydicom\dataset.py in _convert_pixel_data_without_handler(self)
   1554             .format(", ".join([str(hh) for hh in available_handlers]))
   1555         )
-> 1556         raise last_exception  # type: ignore[misc]
   1557 
   1558     def _do_pixel_data_conversion(self, handler: Any) -> None:

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pydicom\dataset.py in _convert_pixel_data_without_handler(self)
   1534         for handler in available_handlers:
   1535             try:
-> 1536                 self._do_pixel_data_conversion(handler)
   1537                 return
   1538             except Exception as exc:

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pydicom\dataset.py in _do_pixel_data_conversion(self, handler)
   1561         # Use the handler to get a 1D numpy array of the pixel data
   1562         # Will raise an exception if no pixel data element
-> 1563         arr = handler.get_pixeldata(self)
   1564         self._pixel_array = reshape_pixel_array(self, arr)
   1565 

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pydicom\pixel_data_handlers\numpy_handler.py in get_pixeldata(ds, read_only)
    281     px_keyword = [kw for kw in keywords if kw in ds]
    282     if len(px_keyword) != 1:
--> 283         raise AttributeError(
    284             "Unable to convert the pixel data: one of Pixel Data, Float "
    285             "Pixel Data or Double Float Pixel Data must be present in "

AttributeError: Unable to convert the pixel data: one of Pixel Data, Float Pixel Data or Double Float Pixel Data must be present in the dataset```
````

Comment: Well, the exception says that your dataset has no pixel data. Have you checked the dataset?

Comment: what have you tried so far ?

Question needs some code:
Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem:  https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 0):

As the exception message says, it's likely that your dataset has no *Pixel Data* element in it. If you're iterating through a folder you're probably picking up a dataset without any image data. Try doing something like this:

```py
from pathlib import Path
from pydicom import dcmread

directory = Path("/path/to/directory")
for p in directory.glob("**/*"):
    ds = dcmread(p)
    if "PixelData" not in ds:
        print(f"Dataset found with no Pixel Data: {p}")
        continue

    arr = ds.pixel_array
```

Answer (score -1):

The medical imagers that I'm familiar with produce 16 bit/pixel gray value images.

Generally `convert` from the ImageMagick suite can read them and save them as e.q. `png`, so you can at least view them and check for good data.

Note that without a specialized display you will loose color resolution.

Comment: You don't lose resolution because of PC hardware. You *may* not be able to see a difference in 16-bit pixel levels without specialised displays, however.